# How can I apply diminish to apheleia-mode

Tags: mode-line, minor-mode

I am using [`diminish`](https://github.com/myrjola/diminish.el) for minor modes. But I was not able to apply it for `apheleia-mode`.

```lisp
(apheleia-global-mode +1)
(with-eval-after-load 'apheleia
  (setf (alist-get 'isort apheleia-formatters)
        '("isort" "--stdout" "-"))
  (setf (alist-get 'python-mode apheleia-mode-alist)
        '(isort black))
  )
(diminish 'apheleia-mode)
(diminish 'apheleia-global-mode)
```

I keep see following `Apheleia` at bottom line:

`Driver.py   ~/program/user Git:dev (home) [Py]  Top (15, 0)  Apheleia------------`

How can I suppress `Apheleia`  word at the bottom line?

Comment: Your mode line looks strange to me, but not calling `diminish` within the `with-eval-after-load` is *probably* your problem (although I'd also expect an error).  (Edit: Or not... assuming `apheleia-global-mode` is autoloaded, given that you called that first, the library should be loaded.)

Comment: Simplest test is `C-h v minor-mode-alist`.  If the `apheleia-mode` entry has associated lighter text then diminish has failed to affect it.  If it doesn't, it's done what you asked it to do, and what's in the mode line is something different (at which point you might start from `C-h v mode-line-format` and drill down into the component vars).

Comment: I believe `apheleia-mode` loaded after a save operation takes (due to Run code formatters on after-save-hook, rather than before-save-hook, and do so asynchronously. ) place in the buffer which cause to run after `diminish` loaded

Comment: I removed following line https://github.com/raxod502/apheleia/blob/75074a2f11e29aeca376b3004270a93ce44e59de/apheleia.el#L1020 , which seems like solved it. Like you said it was lighter text

Comment: The question was cross-posted here: https://github.com/raxod502/apheleia/issues/79

Comment: I wanted to reach developers maybe they make change in their repo related to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```el
(apheleia-global-mode +1)
(with-eval-after-load 'apheleia
  ...
  )
(diminish 'apheleia-mode)
```

Do this:

```el
(diminish 'apheleia-mode)
(apheleia-global-mode +1)
(with-eval-after-load 'apheleia
  (diminish 'apheleia-mode)
  ...
  )
```

Which is weird...

In general if you're using `diminish` you should *always* use it in conjunction with `with-eval-after-load`, because diminish.el doesn't provide for that itself; it trusts that you are only ever using it after loading the library in question.

That said, `apheleia.el` has done something very unexpected here.  Rather than declaring its modes as autoloaded, it has put the full mode definitions into the autoloads file!

This means:

1. `apheleia-mode` and its lighter text are *already* defined as soon as your package manager loads the autoloads file, so you need to `diminish` that immediately, outside of the `with-eval-after-load` form.
2. Your call to `apheleia-global-mode` is *not* loading `apheleia.el` as you might expect.  Instead it arranges (via other autoloads) that the library will be loaded when `after-save-hook` fires.
3. When the `after-save-hook` fires and actually loads the library, `apheleia-mode` is re-defined and your diminished lighter text is clobbered, so you need to `diminish` it again.

Comment: Thanks as always well explained great answer

Comment: Should I `(diminish 'apheleia-global-mode)` as well? or `(diminish 'apheleia-mode)` covers it?

Comment: I think `apheleia-global-mode` has no lighter text of its own.  It's a globalized minor mode controlling `apheleia-mode`, so it doesn't really need to advertise itself like that.  I'm pretty sure `apheleia-mode` is all you care about.

Comment: As update developer added the following option `(apheleia-mode-lighter nil)`